# E2 Studio debugging

Tags: c, debugging, microcontroller, rl78

I have a problem  debugging a simple file using E2 studio with CCRL toolchain. I am using E1 and the target device is the RL78/L13 80 Pins. I receive the following message

```
 Error in final launch sequence
 Failed to execute MI command:
 target extended-remote localhost:61234
 Error message from debugger back end:
 localhost:61234: The system tried to join a drive to a directory on a joined drive.
```

And the E1 is lock up and I have to disconnected from the USB port to reset it.

Comment: What version of e2Studio are you using? What version of E1 firmware are you using? What workstation operating system are you using? (Windows, MAC OS, Linux)